# Load data from database in <h:inputText> with <h:commandButton> or <commandLink>

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

What I'm trying to do is show into  the data information from the database and that information should be able for editing.

I only have one .xhtml page and I would like to have all the CRUD operations in that page.
The current project is working for insert, select and delete.
Thank you, any help will be highly appreciated.

This is the .xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
        <title>#{msgs.indexTitulo}</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:messages errorClass="errors" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msgs.indexTitulo}" styleClass="emphasis"/>


        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                #{msgs.nombrePlaca}
                <h:inputText id="placa" value="#{vehiculo.placa}" required="true" label="#{msgs.nombrePlaca}" />

                #{msgs.marca}
                <h:inputText value="#{vehiculo.marca}" required="true" label="#{msgs.marca}" />


                #{msgs.modelo}
                <h:inputText value="#{vehiculo.modelo}" required="true" label="#{msgs.modelo}"/>


                #{msgs.color}
                <h:inputText value="#{vehiculo.color}" required="true" label="#{msgs.color}"/>


                #{msgs.campoAgencia}   #{msgs.si}
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{vehiculo.agencia}"/>


                #{msgs.anio}
                <h:inputText value="#{vehiculo.anio}" required="true" label="#{msgs.anio}" />
                <br/>


            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.botonSubmit}" action="#{vehiculo.insertVehiculo()}"/>

            <h:button value="Limpiar" type="reset"/>


        </h:form>

        <h:form >

            <!-- -->

            <h:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{vehiculo.seleccionar()}" var="vehiculo">
                <h:column>                  
                    <f:facet name="header">Placa</f:facet>                  
                    #{vehiculo.placa}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Marca</f:facet>
                    #{vehiculo.marca}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Modelo</f:facet>
                    #{vehiculo.modelo}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Color</f:facet>
                    #{vehiculo.color}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                    #{vehiculo.id}
                </h:column>



                <h:column>
                    <h:commandLink value="Eliminar vehiculo" action="#{vehiculo.eliminarVehiculo(vehiculo.id)}"/>

                </h:column>

                <h:column>

                    <h:commandButton value="Actualizar vehiculo" action="#{vehiculo.seleccionarPorID(vehiculo.id)}" >

                     <f:ajax execute="@form" render="myTable" />


                    </h:commandButton>


                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>


            <!-- -->



        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the Bean.

```
    package beans;

import conexionJDBC.ConexionJDBC;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "vehiculo")
@RequestScoped
public class Vehiculo implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Integer placa;
    private String marca;
    private String color;
    private Integer anio;
    private String modelo;   //Modelo del carro, ejemplo: Civic
    private boolean agencia; //Si es comprado en agencia

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(Integer placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Integer getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(Integer anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public boolean isAgencia() {
        return agencia;
    }

    public void setAgencia(boolean agencia) {
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public Vehiculo() {
    }

    public Vehiculo(int id, Integer placa, String marca, String color, Integer anio, String modelo, boolean agencia) {
        this.id = id;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }

    //Metodos para acceder a la BD//
    //INSERT
    public void insertVehiculo() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        ConexionJDBC getConn = new ConexionJDBC();


        try {
            conn = getConn.getConnection();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO vehiculo(placa, marca, color, modelo, anio, agencia) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


            pstmt.setInt(1, placa);
            pstmt.setString(2, marca);
            pstmt.setString(3, color);
            pstmt.setString(4, modelo);
            pstmt.setInt(5, anio);
            pstmt.setBoolean(6, agencia);


            pstmt.executeUpdate();


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        } finally {
            getConn.closeConnection(conn);
            getConn.closeStatement(pstmt);
        }

    }

    //SELECT
    public List seleccionar() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        ConexionJDBC getConn = new ConexionJDBC();


        List<Vehiculo> resultado = new ArrayList();

        try {


            conn = getConn.getConnection();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculo";
            pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            rs = pstm.executeQuery();



            while (rs.next()) {

                Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();

                vehiculo.setPlaca(rs.getInt("placa")); //Importante usar las comillas IMPORTANTISIMO
                vehiculo.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
                vehiculo.setModelo(rs.getString("modelo"));
                vehiculo.setColor(rs.getString("color"));
                vehiculo.setId(rs.getInt("id"));

                /* Antes se hacia asi:
                 placa = rs.getInt(placa);
                 marca = rs.getString(marca);
                 modelo = rs.getString(modelo);
                 color = rs.getString(color);
                 */
                resultado.add(vehiculo);

            }



        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } finally {
            getConn.closeConnection(conn);
            getConn.closeResultset(rs);
            getConn.closeStatement(pstm);
        }
        return resultado;

    }

    //Eliminar
    public void eliminarVehiculo(int id) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        ConexionJDBC getConn = new ConexionJDBC();

        try {
            String sql = "Delete from vehiculo where id=" + id;

            conn = getConn.getConnection();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            getConn.closeConnection(conn);
            getConn.closeStatement(pstmt);
        }

    }

    //UPDATE
    public void actualizarVehiculo(int id) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ConexionJDBC getConn = new ConexionJDBC();

        try {
            conn = getConn.getConnection();

            String sql = "UPDATE vehiculo SET placa=?, marca=?, color=?, modelo=?, anio=?, agencia=? WHERE id=" + id;

            pstm.setInt(1, placa);
            pstm.setString(2, marca);
            pstm.setString(3, color);
            pstm.setString(4, modelo);
            pstm.setInt(5, anio);
            pstm.setBoolean(6, agencia);

            pstm.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } finally {
            getConn.closeConnection(conn);
            getConn.closeStatement(pstm);
        }


    }

    //Select por ID
    public List<Vehiculo> seleccionarPorID(int id) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        ConexionJDBC getConn = new ConexionJDBC();

        List<Vehiculo> resultado = new ArrayList();


        try {

            conn = getConn.getConnection();

            String sql = "Select * from vehiculo where id=" + id;
            pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();

                vehiculo.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                vehiculo.setPlaca(rs.getInt("placa")); //Importante usar las comillas IMPORTANTISIMO
                vehiculo.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
                vehiculo.setModelo(rs.getString("modelo"));
                vehiculo.setColor(rs.getString("color"));
                vehiculo.setId(rs.getInt("id"));

                resultado.add(vehiculo);
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } finally {
            getConn.closeConnection(conn);
            getConn.closeResultset(rs);
            getConn.closeStatement(pstm);
        }

        return resultado;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I load data from database in the <h:inputText> with <h:commandButton> or <commandLink> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you RaSh, thank you dansouza.

I found a way to fill the `<h:inputText>` with the values gotten from the database, and it's really easy.

Just create a method in the ManagedBean:

```
 //Fill the inputText with values
    public void loadFields(int id, int placa, String marca, String modelo, String color, boolean agencia, int anio) {

        //Filling values into the form

        setId(id);
        setMarca(marca);
        setPlaca(placa);
        setModelo(modelo);
        setColor(color);
        setAgencia(agencia);
        setAnio(anio);
    }
```

Then in the .xhtml page:

```
 <h:commandButton value="Actualizar vehiculo" action="#{vehiculoMB.cargarCampos(vehi.id, vehi.placa, vehi.marca, vehi.modelo, vehi.color, vehi.agencia, vehi.anio)}"  >

                    </h:commandButton>
```

I know this is not a best practice, but I am learning JSF yet.

Hope this can be helpful for any who need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorials will be very usefull for you. 2 simple CRUD web applications with JSF:

- [SIMPLE CRUD USING JSF2+HIBERNATE INTEGRATION AND MYSQL](http://javaknowledge.info/simple-crud-using-jsf2hibernate-integration-and-mysql/)
- [Simple CRUD Web Application with JSF 2.1, PrimeFaces 3.5, EJB 3.1, JPA (ORM) / EclipseLink, JAAS , MySQL](http://www.simtay.com/simple-crud-web-application-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-maven-and-jpa/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 mistakes here:
1. seleccionarPorID should return String, not List.
2. You should write method getSeleccionar() which will return `List<Vehiculo>` or Vehiculo[].